# What's the fastest Java collection for single threaded Contains(Point(x,y)) functionality?

Tags: java, collections, points

In my application I need to check a collection of 2D coordinates (x,y) to see if a given coordinate is in the collection,  it needs to be as fast as possible and it will only be accessed from one thread.
( It's for collision checking )

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The absolute fastest I can think of would be to maintain a 2D matrix of those points:

```
//just once
int[][] occurrences = new int[X_MAX][Y_MAX];
for (Point p : points ) {
    occurrences[p.x][p.y]++;
}

//sometime later
if ( occurrences[x][y] != 0 ) {
    //contains Point(x, y)
}
```

If you don't care how many there are, just a `boolean` matrix would work.  Clearly this would only be fast if the matrix was created just once, and maybe updated as Points are added to the collection.

In short, the basic Collections aren't perfect for this (though a `HashSet` would come close).

**Edit**

This could be easily adapted to be a `Set<Point>` if you don't find a library that does this for you already.  Something like this:

```
public class PointSet implements Set<Point> {
    private final boolean[][] data; 
    public PointSet(int xSize, int ySize) {
        data = new boolean[xSize][ySize];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Point e) {
         boolean hadIt = data[e.x][e.y];
         data[e.x][e.y] = true;
         return hadIt;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        Point p = (Point) o;
        return data[p.x][p.y];
    }

    //...other methods of Set<Point>...
}
```

Comment: Agreed: if you don't want to maintain the whole `boolean` matrix, a `HashSet` is probably your best bet.

Comment: Added an implementation of Set based on this principle; note that you'd be best to note where/if it breaks the Set contract.  For example, this doesn't do bounds checking so if you add a Point out-of-range it'll fail.

Answer (score 2):

I would go using some [Trove collections](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/) data structures.

If your points are stored as a couple of `int` or a couple of `float` you can pack them in a `long`: 32 bits for x-coord and 32 bits for y-coord. Then you can use a `TLongHashSet` that is an `HashSet` optimized for working with primitive data (it will be faster and consume less memory compared to normal java collections).

If you have `int` coordinates it would be something like

```
static private long computeKey(int h1, int h2)
{           
    return ((long)h1) << 32 | h2;
}
```

to compute the key and then use it

```
TLongHashSet set = new TLongHashSet()
set.add(long v);
set.addAll(long[] v);
set.containsAll(..);
```

if you have `float` values you can do the same thing, but you have to pack float bits inside the `long`.

Comment: Good suggestion, though one thing to note is you'd probably want to change the hashing strategy used by the `TLongHashSet`.  The default uses `return ((int)(value ^ (value >>> 32))) * 31;` which is good for randomly distributed data but awful for data like this.  Data as simple as (0,1) and (1,0) will result in a hash collision, for example.  It's not good for longs where the first 32 bits has a correlation to the last 32 bits.

Comment: In fact, I ran your `computeKey` against the default hash function for data including every Point with X and Y between 0 and 1000, and it only generated 1024 unique hashes!  That's a hash collision probability of 99.90%!!

Comment: Yes, probably you are right. I used it for a problem similar to this one but that had different distribution of values so it worked like a charm (I've been able to make code that ran 25% faster and saving up to 300-400 Mb of ram out of 2.0 Gb)

Answer (score 1):

HashSet. Its O(1) average. If you want true O(1) you can make a wrapper for your object which has a reference to a collection. That way you cant just compare *it* with the collection you have.

Answer (score 0):

How often do you have to update the collection in comparison to searching it?  You should chose an appropriate data structure based on that.

Point2D implements comparable, right?  Then your best bet is probably a TreeSet, they are incredibly fast and I believe they rely on B+ trees, which you may know are used in actual databases and filesystems.

If you think you're going to be doing a fair amount of updates to the structure, take a look at the SkipList.  It guarentees O(log(operations)) **NOTE this is for ALL operations you do, there is no guarentee about the runtime of a single opperation)

Answer (score -1):

You can try some sort of sorted set, like treeset, since you can do binary searches on it.

Comment: binary search is O(log N) as opposed to the O(1) solutions given in other answers.

Comment: well i guess what you lose in speed you can gain in space usage and flexibility.